# How would I take a string, find a certain character, add a character, and continue until end of string?

Tags: php, postgresql

I’m working on a project where I need to use postgresql to update info. I need to take

Martin’s chik ‘n’ chips

And make change it to

Martin\’s chik \’n\’ chips

How would I do this? I’ve looked at other posts, and found out to use substr() to create the new string and strpos() to find the ‘s, and even setting a new variable to keep the position of the previous ‘

Edit: thanks everyone, clearly didn’t do enough research!

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, you must change your code to correctly escape things.

Comment: Use parameterized queries... or this relates to HTML?

Comment: What's wrong with the original *fancy* quotes? If it's UTF8 all the way through it shouldn't really care...

Comment: @CD001 While when an actual `'` ends up in there it will again break so might as well fix it all now. Although if it were actually the smart quotes it wouldnt cause an issue

Comment: @user3783243 - if it was an actual `'` rather than `‘` or `’` it would be a different question ;) I'm not going to assume the OP screwed the quotes up in MS Word (though that's most likely the case).

Answer (score -1):

If in PHP:
Check out [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). e.g.

```
$text = "Martin’s chik ‘n’ chips";
$apostrophe = array("'","`","‘","’");
$newtext = str_replace($apostrophe,"\'",$text);
```

In this specific example, if you don't have any of the 'fancy' apostrophes, check out [addslashes()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) as this will solve everything for you